# EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY flutter: The following assertion was thrown building PhotosList(dirty, state: _PhotosListState#c298b):

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting run time error on this code.

```
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),

      ),

      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know what could be the problem with this code.

- Ran Flutter doctor
- Clear Cache

```
Widget bodyData() => DataTable(

      sortColumnIndex: 1,
      sortAscending: true,

      columns: <DataColumn>[

        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Company Name"),
          onSort: (_, __) {
            setState(() {
              widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]["companyName"]
                  .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["companyName"]));
            });
          },
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Dividend Yield TT"),
          onSort: (_, __) {
            setState(() {
              widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["stats"]["dividendYield"]
                  .compareTo(b.data["stats"]["dividendYield"]));
            });
          },
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("IEX Bid Price"),
          onSort: (_, __) {
            setState(() {
              widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]["iexBidPrice"]
                  .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["iexBidPrice"]));
            });
          },
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text("Latest Price"),
          onSort: (_, __) {
            setState(() {
              widget.photos.sort((a, b) => a.data["quote"]["latestPrice"]
                  .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["latestPrice"]));
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
      rows: widget.photos
          .map(
            (photo) => DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(
              Text('${photo.data["quote"]["companyName"] ?? ""}'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text("Last Price:"
                  '${photo.data["stats"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text("Dividend Yield22:"
                  '${photo.data["stats"]["dividendYield"] ?? ""}'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text("Last Price:"
                  '${photo.data["quote"]["iexBidPrice"] ?? ""}'),
            ),
            DataCell(
              Text("Last Price:"
                  '${photo.data["quote"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
          .toList());
}
```

---

[image]

> ════════ (6) Exception caught by gesture 
>      ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>      The method 'compareTo' was called on null.
>      Receiver: null
>      Tried calling: compareTo(0.020232447817836813)

[image]

Comment: To start with, your error mentions a PhotosList Widget that you haven't shared with us.Also, you have an error clearly stating that you haven't built your data table correctly. But all of this is difficult to debug due to the amount and format of information.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I have added the missing code.

Comment: You shared where you are using it `PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)`, not what it consists of.

Comment: You defined 4 Columns and giving in data for 5 Columns (see Number of DataCells in row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.of `DataColumn` (headings) and No.of `DataCell` in each row should be same.

In your code, you missing a column heading "State Latest Price" (2nd Column heading)

Try this,

```
Widget bodyData() =>
      DataTable(
          sortColumnIndex: 1,
          sortAscending: true,
          columns: <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("Company Name"),
              onSort: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) =>
                      a.data["quote"]["companyName"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["companyName"]));
                });
              },
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("Stats Latest Price"),
              onSort: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) =>
                      a.data["stats"]["latestPrice"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["stats"]["latestPrice"]));
                });
              },
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("Dividend Yield TT"),
              onSort: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) =>
                      a.data["stats"]["dividendYield"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["stats"]["dividendYield"]));
                });
              },
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("IEX Bid Price"),
              onSort: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) =>
                      a.data["quote"]["iexBidPrice"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["iexBidPrice"]));
                });
              },
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("Latest Price"),
              onSort: (_, __) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.photos.sort((a, b) =>
                      a.data["quote"]["latestPrice"]
                          .compareTo(b.data["quote"]["latestPrice"]));
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
          rows: widget.photos
              .map(
                (photo) =>
                DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text('${photo.data["quote"]["companyName"] ?? ""}'),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text("Last Price:"
                          '${photo.data["stats"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}'),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text("Dividend Yield22:"
                          '${photo.data["stats"]["dividendYield"] ?? ""}'),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text("Last Price:"
                          '${photo.data["quote"]["iexBidPrice"] ?? ""}'),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text("Last Price:"
                          '${photo.data["quote"]["latestPrice"] ?? ""}'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
          )
              .toList());
```

Comment: would you happen to know how to fix the "Right Overflowed" margin?

Comment: can you help w/ this bounty : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999463/the-method-was-called-on-null-receiver-null